# How to add files for the Source code (.zip) dowload on GitHub

Tags: github, github-release

I wanted to share my program on GitHub.
I have a .exe file for the download and the source code for the source code (.zip)
[image: sourcecode]

But how can I add something to the Source code thing? I ended up with something like this.[image]

(The source code files are the "Class" ones and the "main" one, and they are not in the Source code) When I dowload the Source Code there is only the redme.md file inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to, through [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions):

- create a new artifact, for instance a zip file with your actual sources, using for example [`montudor/action-zip`](https://github.com/montudor/action-zip)
- create a release, and upload to said release your artifacts, including the new one created before. You can use [`softprops/action-gh-release`](https://github.com/softprops/action-gh-release)

The idea remains: the "Source code" artifacts automatically created by GitHub are not (from what I can see) modificable.
But you can create your own release and upload/*add* your own artifacts, including one which would have your source code as you want.